# not executable: 64-bit ELF file

Tags: android, linux, go

I am trying to run an golang program in an android physical device

My developer environment:

> uname -a Linux raul-H310M-H 5.15.0-71-generic #78~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
> Wed Apr 19 11:26:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My go version:

> go version go1.20.2 linux/amd64

Android

```
ro.build.version.sdk=29  
ro.build.version.release=10
```

I set these parameters to build it:

```
GOOS=linux 
GOARCH=arm64
CC=~/aarch64-linux-musl-cross/bin/aarch64-linux-musl-gcc
```

go build makes the executable but when I run it in the android device I got:

> not executable: 64-bit ELF file

this device has this architecture:

> Linux localhost 5.4.19-android-x86_64

This very simple code works fine in the android device with GOOS=linux and GOARCH=arm64 and without to set CC:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello Android!\n")
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I got "unrecognized command-line option '-m64'"

Comment: CC=~/x86_64-linux-musl-cross/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc I got gcc_arm64.S: Assembler messages: gcc_arm64.S:30: Error: no such instruction: `stp x29,x30,[sp,'

Comment: On Android it is very important where an executable is saved as there are several folders where execution is restricted. This depends also on the used Android version (which you forgot to tell us).

Comment: I added this information to my question

Answer (score 0):

Your device has an architecture of "5.4.19-android-x86_64", which is an x86_64. However, you compiled your Go program for an arm64 architecture.

To compile your Go program for the x86_64 architecture that your Android uses, you can change the GOARCH environment variable to amd64 and remove the CC environment variable, as follows:

```
GOOS=android
GOARCH=arm64
go build
```

Also, you may need to give it necessary permissions using `chmod +x exec_name`.

Comment: With both I can build fine. First one when I run ti I got: "not executable: 64-bit ELF file" and it has no dynamic libraries. Second one I got: No such file or directory but it contains dynamic libraries: linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3a97e000) libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffabf869000) libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffabf863000) libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffabf671000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffabf8a6000) –

Comment: First one is your code. I'm not sure how, but your linker has a problem. Try setting `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
go build`

Comment: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu is not present in the android device where I need to run my program

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I thought we are building for a Linux device, based on your development logs, I made an assumption that it was device logs. I've updated the answer. I added the GOOS=android part.

Comment: I can not build with GOOS=android and GOARCH=arm64 I got "gcc_android.c:6:10: fatal error: android/log.h". I tried with CC=mypath/arch64-linux-android30-clang It builds but I got "not executable: 64-bit ELF file" when I run it.